# limit woocommerce product short description in home page and category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have included product short description in my home and category pages by adding the following code to my child theme functions.php

`add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);`

Now I would like to limit the characters of product short description in the home and category pages.

Any help please??

**More code and clarifications:** 
My add_action is added to the following file woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php and here are the Product Loop Items.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_open', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_close', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
```

everything is printed here: Mytheme/woocommerce/single-product.php and the code is

```
   <div class="container-inner">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
        <div class="image-block">       
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">        
            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?></a>          
            <div class="product-block-hover"></div>

            </div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="product-name"><?php     the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10 
                 */
                 do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?>                                      

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post more code so I can help you? Show us how do you print them

Comment: Hi @Skatox, I have added more code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Skatox I have added the code that you provided me with in the functions.php of my child theme right before the last php closing tag and it is not working. I also tried to replace woocommerce_short_description with woocommerce_template_single_excerpt() and it is not working too. Any suggestion please?

Comment: I don't see do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' ); in your template file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the lenght with the `woocommerce_short_description` filter, do something like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','limit_short_descr');

function limit_short_descr($description){
  return ($description > 140) ? substr($description, 0 , 140) : $description;
}
```

Also you can add a `&hellip;` after the text to make it look better.

Comment: Yes, your answer helped me solve this problem. thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Skatox for your help, I finally sloved this issue.
Here is what I did:

In the following file(**\wp-contents\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\short-description.php**) I added the following code:

```
<?php
    if ( is_single()):
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt     );
    else :
        echo substr(apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post-    >post_excerpt ),0,140);
    endif;
?>
```

With this, I was able to display the characters I needed in my home and category pages and leave product page as it is.

P.S: the best way to get this done if you are facing the same issue, is to create the same file (short-description.php), edit the code and put it in woocommerce folder in your theme so that your changes are not affected by woocommerce update.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing files directly within the plugin (which is a very bad idea because once update the plugin and all of your changes will be lost!)

create a function and then hook to that filter... something like this...

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'reigel_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1);
function reigel_woocommerce_short_description($post_excerpt){
    if (!is_product()) {
        $pieces = explode(" ", $post_excerpt);
        $post_excerpt = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 10));

    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

paste this in your **functions.php** file of your theme.

**explode** breaks the original string into an array of words, array_splice lets you get certain ranges of those words, and then **implode** combines the ranges back together into single strings.

and **use this line where you want to display product description** -

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
```

use this code to **change Limit** on the **Home  and Category Page not Product-detailed Page**.

Answer (score 0):

I think this the better way. It will limit the short description to 85 characters, Makes your archive page look cleaner:

```
function customize_shop_loop_excerpt() {
function woocommerce_shop_loop_excerpt_custom() {
<p>
<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 85)) . '...'; ?>
</p>
<?php
}
remove_action ('product_box_after', 'woocommerce_shop_loop_excerpt', 20);
add_action ('product_box_after', 'woocommerce_shop_loop_excerpt_custom', 20);
}
add_action ('after_setup_theme', 'customize_shop_loop_excerpt');
```